# Making grayscale map from multiple band satellite image in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, raster-conversion

I have satellite multiple band map, I needs to make grayscale map,what should i do? 
what is the steps?
which band and format of input are to be used in this?
How to make attribute table of this?

In my subject i want to make classification or extraction of some pixel value of grayscale map.for that i requires attribute table. please say me about this all steps. I am new learner in this.

Comment: For band combinations I recommend raster calculator, for an individual band just export it in catalog.

Comment: How to convert color map into grayscale map?

Comment: You have to decide what value 'wins', either max, min or average and then you can use raster calculator to define the output value using Map Algebra http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005m000000mm000000

Comment: i wants value versus count of pixel value. max, min and average not useful for me. I am choosing some particular pixel value and also calculating respective area in map . so i need attribute table of grayscale image.

Comment: Perhaps http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000009000000 and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000005t000000 could help. It looks like you just want to build your raster attribute table which will give you the count of pixels with same value by default.